# Get duration of local video selected using angular

Tags: angularjs, video, duration

Is it possible to validate the duration of a local video that a user has selected using a file input in angular?

I have the following html which binds the selected video to my model.

```
<input type="file" ng-model='video.videoToUpload' accept="video/*" required>
```

The properties of the video in the controller include the filesize and filetype but no duration.  I want to avoid the overhead of submitting the video to the web server just to validate the duration.

Comment: I think this cannot be done using plain angular. you need to look for clientside javascript libraries, if they are available. otherwise upload it to server and check over there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not pure fit for Angular-- But It works!! I have tried with mp4 format.

```js
var myVideos = [];
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
function setFileInfo(files) {
  myVideos.push(files[0]);
  var video = document.createElement('video');
  video.preload = 'metadata';
  video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src)
    var duration = video.duration;
    myVideos[myVideos.length-1].duration = duration;
    updateInfos();
  }
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);;
}

function updateInfos(){
      document.querySelector('#infos').innerHTML="";
  for(i=0;i<myVideos.length;i++){
      document.querySelector('#infos').innerHTML += "<div>"+myVideos[i].name+" duration: "+myVideos[i].duration+'</div>';
     }
  }
```

```html
<div id="input-upload-file" class="box-shadow">
  <span>- Try Upload -</span> 
  <input type="file" class="upload" id="fileUp" name="fileUpload" onchange="setFileInfo(this.files)">
</div>
<div id="infos"></div>
```

Happy Helping!